# What is GHC doing when run with -N (parallel) flag?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, parallel-processing, ghc

I've written the following test application:

```
main = print $ sum $ map (read . show) [1 .. 10^7]
```

When I run it with and without -N flag, I get the following results:

```
$ ghc -O2 -threaded -rtsopts -o test test.hs
...
$ time ./test +RTS -s
50000005000000
real    0m12.411s
user    0m12.367s
sys     0m0.040s
$ time ./test +RTS -s -N12
50000005000000
real    0m22.702s
user    1m14.904s
sys     0m12.608s
```

It seems like GHC decides to honour the -N12 flag by distributing the calculation over different cores (with very bad results), but I can't find any documentation about how exactly it decides to do so when the code doesn't contain explicit instructions. Is there some documentation that I'm missing?

I have GHC version 8.6.5.

Garbage collection statistics:

```js
$ ghc -O2 -threaded -rtsopts -o test test.hs
...
$ time ./test +RTS -s
50000005000000
  54,332,520,712 bytes allocated in the heap
      53,571,832 bytes copied during GC
          56,824 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          29,192 bytes maximum slop
               0 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     52088 colls,     0 par    0.154s   0.150s     0.0000s    0.0001s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0(0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time   12.250s  ( 12.249s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.155s  (  0.151s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.010s elapsed)
  Total   time   12.406s  ( 12.410s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    4,435,169,879 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  98.7% of total user, 98.7% of total elapsed


real    0m12.411s
user    0m12.367s
sys     0m0.040s
$ time ./test +RTS -s -N12
50000005000000
  54,332,687,840 bytes allocated in the heap
     214,001,248 bytes copied during GC
         183,360 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
         146,696 bytes maximum slop
               0 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     52088 colls, 52088 par   20.219s   0.975s     0.0000s    0.0001s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     1 par    0.001s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0002s

  Parallel GC work balance: 0.15% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 26 (1 bound, 25 peak workers (25 total), using -N12)

  SPARKS: 0(0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.007s  (  0.003s elapsed)
  MUT     time   67.281s  ( 21.720s elapsed)
  GC      time   20.221s  (  0.975s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.002s  (  0.003s elapsed)
  Total   time   87.511s  ( 22.701s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    807,549,654 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  76.9% of total user, 95.7% of total elapsed


real    0m22.702s
user    1m14.904s
sys     0m12.608s
```

Comment: You really shouldn't consider what code does when compiled without optimizations as meaningful at all. It's probably not optimizing the allocations out of the computation, and you're seeing the overhead of trying to run the parallel GC on 12 cores. Can you include output with `+RTS -s` for quick GC statistics? (You'll need to add `-rtsopts` when compiling, iirc.)

Comment: @Carl I added the GC statistics to the question. I'll try to see if I can find a minimal working example that shows this behaviour with -O2 then, because I seem to be getting the same issue in my real application even with -O2.

Comment: @Carl, I found an example that works with -O2. I'm going to edit this question, as I believe another question would be way too similar, but I'll revert and ask a new question anyway if you think that's better.

Comment: you can use threadScope utility to see actuall core usage. My guess is that the garbage collector is been parallelize slowing down the whole process. Your code shouldn't be run in parallel since `map` function doesn't run in parallel. Moreover, in your `-N12` execution zero sparks are created, meaning that you aren't running code in parallel. I think...

Comment: @lsmor Any idea why the garbage collector is so slow though, and how that can be avoided? In my actual code, I did obviously run things in parallel, but there was zero performance improvement because whatever is happening here, happens in my real code as well.

Comment: @FrederikVds. I don't know that much... This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R47959rD2yw is a very good resource in parallel haskell as well as simon marlow's book "parallel and concurrent programming in haskell". Apparently, too much parallelism creates more levels of memory indirection that the GC must handle... In the linked video It is shown kind of the same problem you have involving the GC. starting at 30:00

Comment: @lsmor Thanks for the video, looks useful!

Comment: @lsmor It's actually not the same problem. His problem was introduced by adding millions of sparks, and it's intuitive why that would create bad results. My problem is introduced by simply enabling the parallel execution feature of the runtime system while running a completely sequential application. This apparently creates a massive overhead without a clear way to avoid it.

Comment: @FrederikVds what I meant, is that you can use threadScope to see the behaviour of GC. My guess is that it is over-stopping the program... why this behaviour? no clue, but if your program is sequential, why runining in parallel??

Comment: @lsmor I have millions of completely separate computations to do, which I'd like to distribute over 12 threads, but the performance is horrible. As each thread just needs to do its own computations independently, the above program is a simple base case: if I can't even once run sequential code efficiently in the threaded runtime, how am I going to be able to efficiently run that same sequential code 12 times in parallel?

Comment: there are many reason for the sequential code to run slower with this set up, mainly due to GC. Your problem probably isn't related to this one, maybe your are parallelizing too much or any other thing... share a piece of code with the problem you 
are actually running facing, how do you parallelize computations? using `strategies`?, using the `Eval` monad?, etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216932/discussion-between-lsmor-and-frederikvds).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC doesn't automatically parallelize code.  (The runtime system itself may take advantage of multiple threads for initialization giving a small, fixed performance improvement at startup, but that's the only thing that happends "automatically".)

So, your code is running sequentially.  As noted in some of the comments, the bizarre performance problem is probably parallel garbage collection.

Parallel GC has been observed to perform very poorly on certain workloads when running on large numbers of capabilities.  See [issue #14981](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/14981), for example.  Of course, that issue talks about 32- or 64-core machines.

However, I have observed very poor performance **especially with the default runtime GC settings** even on relatively small numbers of cores.  For example, using your test case and GHC version, I get similar poor performance on my 8-core, 16-thread Intel i9-9980HK laptop with `-N12` or more.  Here is the comparison of a 1-capability and 12-capability run.  Compile it:

```
$ cat test.hs
main = print $ sum $ map (read . show) [1 .. 10^7]
$ stack ghc --resolver=lts-14.27 -- -fforce-recomp -O2 -threaded -rtsopts -o test test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )
Linking test ...
```

Run it on one capability:

```
$ time ./test +RTS -N1
50000005000000

real    0m10.803s
user    0m10.770s
sys     0m0.037s
```

Run it on twelve:

```
$ time ./test +RTS -N12
50000005000000

real    0m15.655s
user    0m52.103s
sys     0m7.019s
```

To see that parallel GC is at fault, we can switch to sequential GC:

```
$ time ./test +RTS -N12 -qg
50000005000000

real    0m11.175s
user    0m11.066s
sys     0m0.120s
```

I had assumed that this poor parallel GC performance was related to exceeding the number of physical cores, but your experience suggests this can happen with around 12 capabilities even if it doesn't exceed the physical core count.

Instead of disabling parallel GC entirely, you are advised to play with the runtime [garbage collector controls](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-options-to-control-the-garbage-collector).  The effects can be startling.  For example, increasing the generation 0 allocation area from its default of 1m to 4m results in a big improvement:

```
$ time ./test +RTS -N12 -A4m
50000005000000

real    0m12.485s
user    0m25.219s
sys     0m2.053s
```

and going even higher to 16m eliminates the performance problem entirely, at least for this simple test case.

```
$ time ./test +RTS -N12 -A16m
50000005000000

real    0m11.481s
user    0m11.775s
sys     0m0.126s
```

I get similar improvements switching to compaction for the second generation:

```
$ time ./test +RTS -N12 -c
50000005000000

real    0m11.125s
user    0m11.043s
sys     0m0.089s
```

Of course, running the parallel GC on a reduced number of cores may also help:

```
$ time ./test +RTS -N12 -qn4
50000005000000

real    0m14.092s
user    0m18.961s
sys     0m3.031s
```